# gtk3 get settings value from GtkSettings

Tags: pygobject, gtk3

I want to programmatically retrieve the value of the word wrap setting for GEdit3 from inside a Python plugin.

The [GtkSettings](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.0/GtkSettings.html) class provides a method to [set a string property](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.0/GtkSettings.html#gtk-settings-set-string-property), but how does one **retrieve** the value of a string property? I see no "getter" method.

I have also consulted `pydoc gi.repository.Gtk.Settings` - the methods listed there are the same as the online docs.

I am able to retrieve the property value of interest with the `gsettings` CLI utility. The command `gsettings get org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor wrap-mode`
yields the value `'word'`. I was hoping not to have to use `subprocess.Popen()` just to retrieve this property, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work

```
from gi.repository import Gio
a = Gio.Settings('org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor')
a.get_string('wrap-mode')
```

Since you're using automatic generated bindings, C code samples will work just fine for you, it is just about changing the syntax.

Comment: That works! Although I'm a bit frustrated that there exists this `Gtk.Settings` class which seems useless.